# How can I import text from URL?

Tags: c#, string, import

How can I import [text from URL](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/10571/10571.txt)  to the following c# code?

```
        string text = "Import Text Here";

        string newText= text.ToLower();

        Console.WriteLine(newText);
```

Comment: In order to get better answers to your question please follow the stackoverflow guidelines for asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "*import text* from URL" means, in fact, *download*:

```
  using System.Net;

  ...

  string address = @"http://www.gutenberg.org/files/10571/10571.txt";
  string newText = null;

  HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;
  // in case you work via some kind of proxy
  request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 

  //TODO: simplest; you way want to use Async versions
  using (var response = request.GetResponse()) {
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())) {
      newText = reader.ReadToEnd().ToLower();
    }
  }
```

Now `newText` contains the following text:

```
 the project gutenberg ebook of the old man of the sea, by w.w. jacobs
 ... 
 title: the old man of the sea
   ship's company, part 11.
 ... 
 an alternative method of locating ebooks:
 http://www.gutenberg.net/gutindex.all
```